# Trouble with sorted doubly linked list (java null pointer)

Tags: java, data-structures, nullpointerexception, doubly-linked-list

I am attempting to solve a problem on hackerrank. The question to solve is

"You’re given the pointer to the head node of a sorted doubly linked list and an integer to insert into the list. Create a node and insert it into the appropriate position in the list. The head node might be NULL to indicate that the list is empty."

The Node class they provide is defined as

```
/*
Insert Node at the end of a linked list 
head pointer input could be NULL as well for empty list
Node is defined as 

class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node prev;
}
*/
```

My attempted solution is

```
Node SortedInsert(Node head,int data) 
{
    // new node to insert into linked list
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.data = data;

    if (head == null)
    {  
        return newNode;
    }

    else
    {
        // start at beginning of list
        Node cur = head;

        // traverse through sorted list
        while (cur != null && cur.next != null)
        {        
            if (data < cur.next.data)
            {
                newNode.next = cur.next;
                newNode.prev = cur;
                cur.next.prev = newNode;
                cur.next = newNode;

                return head;
            }

            else
            {
                cur = cur.next;
            }
        }

        return head;
    }
}
```

I am not quite sure what is wrong here, but hackerrank is saying my solution is incorrect. Any idea as to what could be going wrong?

Comment: Have you run your code in an IDE debugger?  _"It doesn't work"_ is insufficient description of the problem.

Comment: I did not try running it in an IDE debugger, but I just figured out the problem myself. Thanks for pointing out the vagueness of my question, I'll keep that in mind next time to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume our DLL is 1=2=3=4=5

Now consider the case : add 6 to DLL
The loop does not cover the corner cases.

```
    while (cur != null && cur.next != null)
    {        
        if (data < cur.next.data)
        {
            newNode.next = cur.next;
            newNode.prev = cur;
            cur.next.prev = newNode;
            cur.next = newNode;

            return head;
        }

        else
        {
            cur = cur.next;
        }
    }
```

Modification :

```
    if(data < cur.data) {
            newNode.next = cur;
            newNode.prev = null;
            cur.prev = newNode;

            head  = newNode;
            return head;
    }

    while (cur != null)
    {        
        if (data >= cur.data)
        {   
            if(cur.next == null) {
                 newNode.next = cur.next;
                 newNode.prev = cur;
                 cur.next = newNode;

                 return head;    
            }

            newNode.next = cur.next;
            newNode.prev = cur;
            cur.next.prev = newNode;
            cur.next = newNode;

            return head;
        }

        else
        {
            cur = cur.next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I literally just figured out I wasn't checking that right before you posted this! Thank you anyway!